Geyser notify_transaction pre broadcast
If you use a geyser plugin to notify_account and notify_transaction, does it only notify after track banking stage in broadcast stage? Or does it notify on validator receipt of transaction and account whether leader or not leader

The transaction_status_sender, whose accompanying receiver is given to the geyser plugin manager, is given to both the TPU (banking stage) and TVU (replay stage), so it works when the node is the leader and also when it's validating.
The sender is created at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/3ee204b5cba93211fa0e07dc9238372eeb7933db/core/src/validator.rs#L2286, so depending on your questions, you can follow this variable and see where it's used in core/src/tpu.rs and core/src/tvu.rs
